# angular 4 ngOnChanges not shows the changes

Tags: angular, typescript, events

I'm try to use with ngOnChanges in angular 4 but I don't see any it work.

login.component.ts

```
    import { AuthService } from './../../services/auth.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges,SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges {
    returnUrl: string;
    signInForm: FormGroup;
    errorMsg: any;


    constructor(
        private userService: AuthService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private fb: FormBuilder) {
            this.signInForm = fb.group ({
                'email' : new FormControl(null, Validators.compose([Validators.email, Validators.required])),
                'password': new FormControl(null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]))
              });
         }

    login() {

        this.userService.login({email: this.signInForm.value.email, password: this.signInForm.value.password})
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.router.navigate(['']);

                },
                error => {
                    this.errorMsg = error._body;
                    console.log(this.errorMsg);
                });
    }
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if(changes.email){
            console.log("email input change");
        }
    }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

login.component.html

```
    <form [formGroup]="signInForm" (ngSubmit)="login()">    
<div class="ui middle aligned center aligned grid">
  <div class="column">
    <h2 class="ui teal image header">
      <div class="content">
        Log-in to your account
      </div>
    </h2>
    <div class="ui large form">
      <div class="ui stacked segment">
        <div class="field">
          <div class="ui left icon input">
            <i class="user icon"></i>
            <input type="text" name="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="E-mail address">
          </div>
          <span
```

as you can see here in ngOnChanges function

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if(changes.email){
            console.log("email input change");
        }
    }
```

I just check if email input has change e.g if someone type or something, but I don't see the change, I don't see it print anything in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **`ngOnChanges`** on input if you are using a child component, In your case simply use **`(change)="onChange($event)"`**

```
 <input type="text" name="email"  [(ngModel)]="email"  (change)="onChange($event)"`** formControlName="email" placeholder="E-mail address">
```

Comment: but why it's working after I finish to type and press tab and not during the typing?

Comment: Then use (input)="onChange($event)

Comment: even better using (ngModelChange) so you avoid interference with standard change events